# Detect second click on button

Tags: jquery, click, addclass, detect

I want to change CSS on a button. On the first click, and on the second.
I have this but it doesn't work. Never add .clic-two

```
$(".prev-next-links li.no-clic").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('no-clic');
    $(this).addClass('clic-one');
});

$(".prev-next-links li.clic-one").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('clic-one');
    $(this).addClass('clic-two');
});
```

Comment: Add your `html` also and improve your question

Comment: need to add more info to question is this every second click?or just first and second? things like that needs clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing it is by using the common class as the selector. Since the DOM is dynamic you would have to use the CSS class that is not changing after a user interaction.

```js
$(".prev-next-links, .prev-next-links a").click( function() {

   if ($(this).hasClass("no-clic")) {
 
     $(this).removeClass('no-clic');
     $(this).addClass('clic-one');
   } else if ($(this).hasClass("clic-one")) {
     $(this).removeClass('clic-one');
     $(this).addClass('clic-two');
   }



 });
```

```css
.prev-next-links {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.no-clic {
  background-color: gray;
}
.clic-one {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.clic-two {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="prev-next-links no-clic">First
  </li>
  <li class="prev-next-links"><a class="no-clic" href="#">Second</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're removing/adding the class which means the property on the DOM is dynamic. And for the dynamic elements, you need to use event delegation method to work:

```
$(".prev-next-links").on('click','li.no-clic',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('no-clic');
    $(this).addClass('clic-one');
});
$(".prev-next-links").on('click','li.click-one',function() {
    $(this).removeClass('clic-one');
    $(this).addClass('clic-two');
});
```

Learn more about [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

---

But I would suggest you to set a flag variable to check if it is clicked second time:

```
var clickedTime = 0;
$(".prev-next-links li").click(function() {
    clickedTime++;
    $(this).toggleClass('click-one',clickedTime % 2 == 0);
});
```

Look for [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) docs.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you dynamically assign the `.clic-one` class after the page has loaded, yet you are hooking the click event to the `.click-one` buttons on load before they exist.

To solve this problem you should use delegated event handlers:

```
$('.prev-next-links').on('click', '.no-clic', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('no-clic clic-one');
}).on('click', '.clic-one', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('clic-one clic-two');
});
```

Also note the single call to `toggleClass()` over the use of `addClass()`/`removeClass()` separately.